# How I would scrape a poorly structured HTML page with few CSS selectors using Rails and Nokogiri?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I have been trying to scrape a poorly structured HTML site http://lovegan.com/supplementalfoodcat.html.

This is not my website or my business, but as a customer I spend lots of time searching for what I want to buy and it's not easy.

The page doesn't have CSS selectors or HTML divs to play with. I have tried Nokogiri's `inner_text` method but it didn't help me much or, I was not able to go far with it except gathering all text on the page.

What I'm looking for as the final result is to organize all these sections or categories similar to http://organic.foodoro.com/. I want to organize products by categories.

I have searched online for how to scrape similar HTML using Nokogiri but found nothing.

How I would do that?

Comment: First, you need to show us code so we can see what things you've tried. Or, at least, explain better how you searched without finding how to do it. The [Nokogiri docs](http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/searching_a_xml_html_document.html) explain it, as do any number of pages on this site. CSS selectors don't require anything except the regular markup tags, so they're your first choice.

Answer (score 0):

These is the basics for using CSS:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<html>
<body>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>bar</p>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>today</td>
      <td>tomorrow</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
EOT

doc.at('p').text # => "foo"
doc.search('p').last.text # => "bar"
doc.at('table td').text # => "today"
doc.search('body table tr td').last.text # => "tomorrow"
doc.search('td').last.text # => "tomorrow"
```

Take the time to read [Nokogiri's tutorials](http://nokogiri.org/tutorials), and the [Nokogiri::XML::Node](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html) documentation.

`at` finds the first node that matches a CSS or XPath selector. It has `at_css` and `at_xpath` as equivalents.

`search` finds all matching nodes that match a CSS or XPath selector. It has `css` and `xpath` as equivalents.